# CI/CD Kubernetes Deployment using Github Actions

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, pipeline, github-actions, continuous-deployment

We are thinking about migrating our infrastructure to Kubernetes.
All our Source-code is in GitHub, Docker containers are in Docker Hub.

I would like to have a CI/CD pipeline for Kubernetes only using GitHub and Docker Hub. Is there a way?

If not, what tools (as few as possible) should we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go it as per need using the Github Action and Docker hub only.

You should also checkout the keel with GitHub :https://github.com/keel-hq/keel

**Step: 1**

```
name: Stable Build
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "*.*.*"
...
      - name: Set tag in env
        run: echo "TAG=${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
...
          tags: runq/go-kube:${{ env.TAG }}, runq/go-kube:latest
```

**Step : 2**

Once build is done you can push it to Docker Hub

**Step : 3**

Keel can auto-update the deployment, but if you don't want that you can each time apply the YAML config from Github action also.

Read more at : https://dev.to/achu1612/ci-cd-for-kubernetes-using-github-actions-and-keel-4b7c

If you are planning to use Azure you should checkout : https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-kubernetes-cluster

Answer (score 0):

An example of using Github Actions to manage k8s clusters in the GITOPS style: https://github.com/skosachiov/ansiblecd

A commit to the devel git branch automatically rolls out changes to the devel environment, a commit (merge from devel) to the prod branch makes changes to the prod environment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34609212)